# Error de Imagenes en Render.com

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, static

el error que estoy teniendo es que cuando quiero levantar mi aplicación web de Django en render.com me toma los archivos estáticos, pero no las imágenes que ya tengo subidas ni las que suben los usuarios.

```
Settings.py

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'rutina/static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'controler/static'),
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'  
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

model.py 

class Ejercicio(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
    imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to= "rutina/image/")
```

Cuando lo pruebo en mi servidor local funciona perfecto, pero al subirlo no.
Muchas gracias y disculpen si es una pregunta fácil, es mi primer App Web a subir.